# How can I take a .exe ported from python (py2exe) and run it as a background process?

Tags: batch-file, python-2.7, exe, py2exe

I wrote a program in IDLE and made it into an EXE via py2exe.  I want it to run in the background and whenever I start up my computer.  How could I do this?  Should I implement a piece of code into the original script, or do I need to create a BATCH file, or do I need to do something else?  I'm fairly new to programming so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to your startup folder:

```
C:\users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

For one user;

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

For all users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Will try shortly.

Comment: I tried the solution, and the program does launch successfully on startup.  Unfortunately, the program does not run as a background task.  My end goal is to have the program run and the user, me, not have to see it.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background

Comment: I tried the solutions save for the batch file one, because it didn't really apply to what I was trying to do.  To clarify, I want the program to not have a window or an icon on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: That is a very different question from the one you asked. Best I can do there is suggest you add a piece of code that minimizes python when it starts.

Comment: My apologies.  I thought that "in the background" meant invisible.

Comment: Well, it *can* mean that, but I assumed it wasn't what you were looking for. Your question implied you wanted it to run on startup, behind everything else, and that it didn't load a UI (hence, background). If you'd like to look for this specifically, try looking for ways to hide the python console. First google search result says to save the file as a ".pyw", suppressing the console. Maybe try that?

Comment: I had no idea that pyw's were designed to do that.  You are awesome.  The program runs successfully.